# How do I implement a callback from the windows native api in c#?

Tags: c#, native, wlanapi

I have a native api function which looks like:

```
DWORD WINAPI WlanRegisterNotification(
  __in        HANDLE hClientHandle,
  __in        DWORD dwNotifSource,
  __in        BOOL bIgnoreDuplicate,
  __in_opt    WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK  funcCallback,
  __in_opt    PVOID pCallbackContext,
  __reserved  PVOID pReserved,
  __out_opt   PDWORD pdwPrevNotifSource
);
```

I have translated it to C# as:

```
[DllImport("Wlanapi.dll", EntryPoint = "WlanRegisterNotification")]
public static extern uint WlanRegisterNotification(
     IntPtr hClientHandle, WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE dwNotifSource,
     bool bIgnoreDuplicate, WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK funcCallback,
     IntPtr pCallbackContext, IntPtr pReserved,
     [Out] out WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE pdwPrevNotifSource);
```

The callback function looks like:

```
typedef VOID ( WINAPI *WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK)(
  PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA data,
  PVOID context
);
```

I am guessing the C# version will look something like:

```
public delegate void WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK(
    IntPtr pWlanNotificationData, IntPtr pContext)
```

Essentially I have two questions:

Is a delegate the correct object to use for a native method that expects a function pointer?

And if so, will this automatically call the delegate in c# when the notification is received?

Comment: see http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wlanapi.WlanRegisterNotification for how the delegate should like.

Comment: Not actually any information about the delegate there :(

Comment: On top of the page it says: public delegate void WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK(ref WLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA notificationData, IntPtr context);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use a delegate, and yes, it will work fine.

However, you must make sure that the GC does not collect your delegate instance. (typically by putting it in a field)